# Using iFrame to load local html file

Tags: html, css, iframe

I'm trying to write a student web site for school using only html5 and css3. I want to showcase all of the websites I've made in an iFrame within my student web site using only local files but it's not loading anything. Here's the code I'm using:

```
<iframe src="yoga/ch7/index.html" name="frame"></iframe>
  <p>
    <a href="yoga/ch7/index.html" target="frame"><span>Home</span></a>
    <a href="yoga/ch7/classes.html" target="frame"><span>Classes</span></a>
    <a href="yoga/ch7/schedule.html" target="frame"><span>Schedule</span></a>
  </p>
```

and this is what I'm seeing:
[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7sEDV.png)

Comment: Looks like a problem with your src path. Make sure your path does point to the file you want to display. Can you add your project's structure?

Comment: Wow, thanks @SeppeDev and Midz Elwekil, I completely overlooked the fact that I haven't finished ch7 htmls yet, my fault.
But after changing the links to html files I've completed, it works great.

Comment: Good to hear! Make sure to accept the answer of Midw Elwekil if it helped you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have tried your code and it did work on my computer, please make sure the src="url" is correct.

copy and paste (yoga/ch7/index.html) it in your browser and make sure there's a result